# SQL Table column to array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

How do I get the values in one column to an array? In the example table I want all the names in the column "NAME" to "my_array".

```
Ex. (my_table)
|ID|NAME   |
------------
|1 |my_name|
------------
|2 |my_name|
--------------------------------------------------

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM my_table");

$my_array = array();
$column = 'NAME';

$i=1;    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $my_array [$i]=$row[$column];
    $i++;
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean ? 
 
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $my_array [$i][$column]=$row;
    $i++;
}`

Answer (score 0):

First, dont set `$i = 1`, because an array starts at 0, not at 1.
Than, I would use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`.

```
$i=0;    
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $my_array[$i] = $row[$column];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code should work, if you are just looking for a more efficient way to do it, have a look at searching databases with PDO and use can use

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$database.';host='.$host, $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ID FROM my_table'); 
$stmt->execute();    
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$myarray = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo $myarray[0]['ID'].','.$myarray[1]['ID']; //etc
```

If you are after just one column, just select that one not * if you are after more than one.